# mesh in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How can you plot a finer mesh like at noninteger values or something? My function is defined for only a very narrow range and Id like to visualize it better with the mesh. Also how do you make the function white? There is no "White" ColorData.

Answer (score 2):

Your color question:

The default color is white for plots, with different colored lighting being used by default to make the plot appear non-white.

You can use the [Lighting](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Lighting.html) option (`Lighting -> "Neutral"`) to get non-colored lighting in 3D plots. Then the result is white/grayscale:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

Your mesh question:

More information or an example is needed to answer this question. But try examining the [PlotPoints](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotPoints.html) option in the documentation to start.